# Fetch data from API and pass the fetched data as parameter to other API to fetch regarding data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, redux

I am working on an app and getting all the data from  API's for different components.And when calling login api I am getting the json as response with user details. I have a component which requires some of the user details to pass to another API to fetch regarding data. Currently I am fetching data of the components by passing actual user details as a parameter to the API, and I want to make it dynamic.

Where Whenever a user will logged in, other API's should dynamically take the required parameters and fetch the json data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create an async function that logs the user in and on the result, call the second API conditionally with the result of the login call.

```
async function loginUser (params){
  try {
    // api call here
    // if everything is successful 

    return { 
      success:true,
      data: userObject
    }

  }  catch(e){
    return{
      success:false,
      error:e
    }
  }
}

const result = loginUser(params)
if(result.success){
  // perform another call whcich requires userObject
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this but getting data undefined, do have any reference. Thanks in advance